# how to write tests for service in angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular7

Below is `Angular7` `Http` service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { map, retryWhen, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

    import { AddCustomer as Transaction} from '../../module/model/add-Customer.model';


    const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })};

    @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class CustomerService {
     constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
     public addCustomer(newTransaction: Transaction): Observable<Transaction> 
    {
     console.log(newTransaction);
     return this.http.post<Transaction>('', newTransaction, httpOptions)
    }
```

But not sure how do I write tests against this service.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [ MyService ]
});

const myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
```

run your tests against myService.

If your service has dependencies, you need to include those in the providers array as well.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Angular's documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests) the simplest way to test a service is just to create an instance of your service as any other class instance. (Services are lightweight classes ... but not the components).

```
describe('MasterService without Angular testing support', () => {
  const client= new HttpClient(null);
  spyOn(client, 'get').and.returnValue(Observable.of(response));
  let service: CustomerService = new CustomerService(client);
```

You can also use Angular's testing utilities as Tzannetos Philippakos suggested. It is necessary to test components and it can also spare some setup efforts.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    providers: [CustomerService ]
});
```